# sencha app build and index.php file; update build

Tags: cmd, build, extjs6

I developed a small application with extjs 6.6.0 and PHP in order to know better some aspects of this version.

The index file of the application is index.php with html, css, javascript and some php scripts.

I did the build with cmd.

Instead of an index.**php** file it generates an index.**html** file in the production app.

**First question:** is it correct to directly change the file extension of the production app index.html to index.php?

**Second question:** whenever I want to update the production app I have to use the command sencha app build?

If so, each time I made a new build, an index.**html** file will be created.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: I've never tried this https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?275806-Change-from-index-html-to-index-php but it may help you. My first suggestion, don't change from index.html as that is how Sencha handles their single page development. Second question, yes, app build will rebuild all files including the index.html.